# How to write Javascript for setChoiceValueByRecodeValue for matrix questions in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm having Qualtrics autopopulate question choices from an embedded data field using setChoiceValueByRecode Javascript. I've been able to successfully do this for single and multi-select multiple-choice questions but cannot figure it out for *matrix* questions.

Here's an example of what works in multiple-choice questions using ( recodeValue  [subID]  value ), with no subID because it's not needed for multiple-choice questions:

```
 Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var answer = "${e://Field/DEMOGRAPHICs_Gender}"; 
    var that = this;  
    switch(answer){
        case "Male":
            that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(1, true);
            break;
        case "Female":
            that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(2, true);
            break;
        case "Non-binary":
            that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(3, true);
            break;
        case "Prefer not to answer":
            that.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(4, true);
            break;
        default: 
            break; 
    }

});
```

The [documentation from Qualtrics](https://s.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html#method_setChoiceValue) around this suggests that for matrices, I need to specify a [subID] to inform which row of the matrix to reference but **I can't figure out what this [subID] is or where to find it.**

E.g. For [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLZ9e.png)...I've tried using "Amazon" as a subID with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

subID (second argument) is the recode for the answer (column if the matrix isn't transposed).  The id (first argument) is the choice id (row if matrix isn't transposed). So selecting the first row and first column would likely look like:

```
this.setChoiceValueByRecodeValue(1, 1, true);
```